# unexpected situation while reading arguments from telnet

Tags: c, sockets, websocket, telnet

**Explanation:**

I want to send a message from telnet and do something to the server according to this message, but unexpected situations occur when comparing the message from telnet.

I want the server to be stopped when a "quit" message is sent from telnet, but when I print the incoming message to the screen, the strcmp() function does not perform its function, even though message equals "quit".

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    // for strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> // for inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    // for write
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char message[1000];
    char received_message[1000];
     
    // Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        puts("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }
     
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;  //IPv4 Internet protocols
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //IPv4 local host address
    server.sin_port = htons(8895); // server will listen to 8895 port
     
    // Bind
    if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("Binding failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Socket is binded");
     
    // Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
     
    // Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket= accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t*)&c);
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        puts("Accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
     
    puts("Connection accepted");
    //message = "\n\nHello client, I received your connection. Bye now\n\n";
    int choice = 1;

    while(choice != 0){

        recv(new_socket, received_message, 1000, 0);
        int ret = strcmp(received_message,"quit");
        printf("\nreturn value of strcmp():%d\n",ret);
        printf("\nreceived message:%s",received_message);

        if(ret == 0){
            choice = 0;
        }
       
    }

    close(socket_desc);
    close(new_socket); 

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

**Telnet Console:**
[image: Telnet Console]

**Server Console:**

[image: Server Console]

what's wrong with this code? Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm no expert on Telnet protocol, but you should check if it is sending newlines, escape sequences, and string terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: `server.sin_port = htons(8895); // server will listen to 8888 port`  And that's why comments that simply repeat the code are worse than useless...

Comment: Yeah, when `strcmp` fails to give you the right result, it helps to print out each character of the two strings you are comparing *as integers* so you can see the string the same way your C program sees it.  Then you can figure out what extra stuff is in the string and think about how to trim it off.

Comment: Note that `printf("\nreceived message:%s",received_message);` does *not* finish with a hard newline in the format string, but your console output *did* (according to the cursor position on the line following that output). That tells you the string has more than just `"quit"` in the mix. It *likely* has `"quit\n"` or some other such suffix, and as such will not compare against `"quit"` with perfect equivalence.

Comment: thank you all, thanks to you i detected the problem and solved it using received_message[strcspn(received_message, "\r\n")] = 0;

Comment: 'recv(new_socket, received_message, 1000, 0);' no.  Please read TCP RFC and spec for read().  You MUST NOT ignore the result returned by read().  'SOCK_STREAM' means something important.